# Using "empty interfaces" in dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm currently thinking if using "empty interfaces" (aka. marker interfaces), which are generally considered as code smell, is a good approach when using dependency injection.

Example:

```csharp
interface IWorkspace
{
   ... // some definitions here
}

interface IDynamicWorkspace : IWorkspace { }

interface IStaticWorkspace : IWorkspace { }

class Workspace1 : IDynamicWorkspace 
{
   ... // IWorkspace implementation
}

class Workspace2 : IStaticWorkspace 
{
   ... // IWorkspace implementation
}

class WorkspaceProvider
{
   IEnumerable<IWorkspace> GetWorkspaces()
   {
      if (someCondition)
          return diContainer.GetServices<IDynamicWorkspace>();
      else
          return diContainer.GetServices<IStaticWorkspace>();
   }
}
```

For me this approach makes sense, but perhaps there is a better solution for this problem.

BTW: I'm using C# and Microsoft's DependencyInjection implementation, but I guess this problem also applies to other languages and frameworks.

Comment: For us to comment on whether this is a good approach, or whether there is a perhaps more suitable design, much more details are needed.

Comment: Usually a factory is used to get a specific instance by condition.